# .htaccess restricting $_GET

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a project for modification, where I need to post a form with get, but I am unable to get the post value.

after checking I determine that .htaccess causing problem for this, please help me on this so I get the value without affecting the existing functionality of site.

this is .htaccess file

```
RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z0-9_+-\s+]+)$ ?x=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z0-9_+-\s+]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_+-\s+]+)$ ?x=$1&y=$2

RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z0-9_+-\s+]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_+-\s+]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_+-\s+]+)$ ?    x=$1&y=$2&z=$3
RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z0-9_+-\s+]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_+-\s+]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_+-\s+]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_+-\s+]+)$ ?x=$1&y=$2&z=$3&u=$4    
RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z0-9_+-\s+]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_+-\s+]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_+-\s+]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_+-\s+]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_+-\s+]+)$ ?x=$1&y=$2&z=$3&u=$4&v=$5  
RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z0-9_+-\s+]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_+-\s+]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_+-\s+]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_+-\s+]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_+-\s+]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_+-\s+]+)$ ?x=$1&y=$2&z=$3&u=$4&v=$5&w=$6
RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z0-9_+-\s+]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_+-\s+]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_+-\s+]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_+-\s+]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_+-\s+]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_+-\s+]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_+-\s+]+)$ ?x=$1&y=$2&z=$3&u=$4&v=$5&w=$6&a=$7
RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z0-9_+-\s+]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_+-\s+]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_+-\s+]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_+-\s+]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_+-\s+]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_+-\s+]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_+-\s+]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_+-\s+]+)$ ?x=$1&y=$2&z=$3&u=$4&v=$5&w=$6&a=$7&b=$8
```

eg : http://www.exampledomain.com/result?term=sampleterm

in this the $_GET['x'] value is result, but I am unable to get term value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually need `QSA` flag (Query String Append), and its better to use `L` (Last) flag also.

```
RewriteRule ^/?([\w\s+-]+)/?$ ?x=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^/?([\w\s+-]+)/([\w\s+-]+)/?$ ?x=$1&y=$2  [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/?([\w\s+-]+)/([\w\s+-]+)/([\w\s+-)/?$ ?x=$1&y=$2&z=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/?([\w\s+-]+)/([\w\s+-]+)/([\w\s+-]+)/([\w\s+-]+)/?$ ?x=$1&y=$2&z=$3&u=$4 [L,QSA]

# rest of the rules here...
```

QSA  flag makes sure to append existing query string in the new query parameter you're adding through your rules.